# Design for Multiple I2C slave devices

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, i2c, beaglebone-black

I'm doing a PCB in which I'm using the Beagle Bone Black to interact with multiple I2C devices. I have attached a schematic. Out of the many I2C devices, I'm connecting some using [TI's I2C switch PCA9548A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pca9548a.pdf) (mainly for reducing the line capacitance).

I have the following questions

1. Does my schematic make sense? Are there any glaring loopholes
2. For the purpose of de-bugging (to see waveform quality, rise time etc), I bring out the main SDA, SCL lines and the switch lines SDA (1-4) and SCL(104) to 0.1 inch 2 Position headers (**as shown in the Figure 2**). Does bringing out I2C lines like this hurt the signal integrity and overall performance? Also am I doing it right?
3. Since multiple devices use the same I2C lines, the section where the lines meet looks **as shown in Figure 1.** The white circles indicate the intersection of SDA/SCL lines from other devices. Does this make sense?

Thanks

Figure 1
[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]
Figure 2

Comment: Schematic images posted looks ok. What is the max speed u r operating. Those headers shouldn't disturb you...

Comment: Just curious: how did you create the board when you don't have a real schematic? Or did you omit the schematic in your post?

Comment: I do have a schematic. Its distributed over 13 pages. For simplicity I enclosed the above schematic or should I say 'OmniGraffle block diagram'

Answer (score 3):

> Does my schematic make sense? Are there any glaring loopholes

The most glaring omission is the fact that this is an OmniGraffle block diagram, not a schematic. A reasonable schematic would show all connections and components.

> For the purpose of de-bugging (to see waveform quality, rise time etc), I bring out the main SDA, SCL lines and the switch lines SDA (1-4) and SCL(104) to 0.1 inch 2 Position headers (as shown in the Figure 2). Does bringing out I2C lines like this hurt the signal integrity and overall performance? Also am I doing it right?

No it doesn't hurt it. I do it with SPI all the time which can be much, much faster than I2C. I don't see how you could mess that part up!

> Since multiple devices use the same I2C lines, the section where the lines meet looks as shown in Figure 1. The white circles indicate the intersection of SDA/SCL lines from other devices. Does this make sense?

You need to eliminate acute angles to reduce acid traps for board etching. Otherwise I2C is **SO SLOW** that you can treat it as a wire on a PCB. You can't get anything long enough on a circuit board for stub lengths or termination to matter. It gets a little more iffy when you start taking it between PCBs and over cables though.

The only thing I see here that looks weird is the low-speed resistors in the main branch (4.7k) and the high-speed resistors in the child branches (2k). Usually you use a lower resistance pull-up when you're running at 400kHz and 4.7k when you're running at 100kHz.

Note: This is not a 'normal*' mux.. rather it is a 'branch selector' that can have many or no branches connected. Your control byte, defined as
[image]

is used to select the MOSFET switches individually

[image]

and you can turn on or off any branch arbitrarily.

*A normal mux would code to 001 -> 00000001, 010 -> 00000010, 011 -> 00000100...

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I think the 2k resistor is a good catch. The datasheet for PCA9548A does not give the resistors and I dont recall the reason I chose 2k over 4.7k. Entire system is at 100KHz. So I'll make the following changes 1) Change 2k --> 4.7k and 2) Make angles less acute (Although it will still work without this). Thanks!

Comment: That looks like Altium. You should set the Acute Angles rule. Typically I shoot for 90, but 70-80 works I guess.

Comment: Also, do you realize that this mux can tie all of the busses together simultaneously? It's not a 'normal' mux, but more of a bus with on-off switches.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last comment? I didn't really understand the difference between this mux and the normal one.

Comment: @Agm I addressed it with an edit by adding some pictures from the datasheet. Where I said 'normal mux' I probably meant 'demux' ha